# Infineon TriCore TC1797 assembly instruction JGE

Tags: assembly

I am looking at TriCore TC1797 code, and matching Instruction set manual TriCore V1.3.1 Instruction set.

My question is trivial, yet the Tasking compiler generated assembly code is puzzling me. The code looks like it will loop forever, yet it doesn't, the code works. How is it possible?

Lets take these instruction lines (the comments are my understanding of operation):

```
MOVH.A a12, #@HIS(VAR_ADDRESS)
LEA    a12, [a12]@LOS(VAR_ADDRESS)
LD.H   d15, [a12]0          ; d15 = 4 (half-word) passed to this function
                            ; values passed are either 0x04 or 0x10 or 0xA8

loop_addr:
ADD    d15, d15, #-0x10     ; d15 = 4 - 0x10 = 0xFFFFFFF4
EXTR   d9, d15, #0, #16     ; d9 = 0x0000FFF4
                            ; edit: THIS IS MY MISTAKE
                            ; correct is d9 = 0xFFFFFFF4
... 
    other code here, never touching d9
...
ST.H   [a12], d9            ; store decremented value back
JGE    d9, #1, loop_addr    ; ???? comparing 0x0000FFF4 to 1
                            ; will it loop forever?
```

What I do not understand, since the d9 is always a positive number (right?), which is never going to be a zero, how is it possible, that the loop exits?

Thank you for clarifying it, I re-read this in the manual but cannot find explanation for this situation.

Comment: Typically you have conditional jumps for both signed and unsigned comparisons. Is there something like a `ja` instructions?

Comment: Since there is a `JGE.U` for unsigned, clearly `JGE` is signed. Hence,  it will be treated as signed, but positive since your `d9` has been masked down to `0x0000FFF4`. Thus it doesn't matter whether you use signed or unsigned comparison.

Comment: fuz: this is definitely JGE (and not JGE.U) instruction, so it is signed comparison

Comment: Jester: do I understand you correctly: it will jump to jumping_addr then? (and you approved my comments after the instructions?)

Comment: Yes it will jump. Verify in a debugger ;)

Comment: *"in 32 bit CPU, 0x0000FFF4 is a positive number?"* - yes, indeed. The 0x80000000 bit is used as sign bit in 32b integers (well, usually, there may be CPUs using different value encoding than binary two's complement, but from the looks of initial part of your example this CPU looks to work in the common way where ~0 == -1 and INT_MAX = (1<<31)-1, INT_MIN = (1<<31) ).

Comment: Jester: sorry to bug you again, as you see I spent another few hours before asking: I edited the above code to be more clear with my question. I also see it working, as you described, but that would make it looping forever (right?) but the code works fine. How is that possible?

Comment: Actually the issue is that we trusted you when you said `d9 = 0x0000FFF4`. That's wrong. `EXTR` sign extends the extracted bitfield, so `d9` is actually `0xFFFFFFF4`, and that is negative and handled as such by `JGE`.

Comment: Thank you Jester! This comment is below as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ADD    d15, d15, #-0x10     ; d15 = 4 - 0x10 = 0xFFFFFFF4
EXTR   d9, d15, #0, #16     ; d9 = 0x0000FFF4
```

This is the mistake. `EXTR` sign extends the extracted bitfield. To quote the [manual](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/tc_v131_instructionset_v138.pdf?fileId=db3a304412b407950112b409b6dd0352):

> The EXTR instruction fills the most-significant bits of the result by
>   sign-extending the bit field extracted (duplicating the
>   most-significant bit of the bit field).

Thus `d9` is actually `0xFFFFFFF4`. `JGE` uses signed comparison, so that is properly treated as `-12` and terminates the loop.

Comment: Thank you!!! I upvoted this correct answer, but it will show only after my reputation goes above 15.